# Vote-up arrow cut off.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The vote-up arrow appears cropped. I looked at the sprite image, and it's fine there, so some css trick is chopping it.

[image]

Comment: Good catch. I think it's supposed to be `background-position: 0 -240px;` (instead of `-241px`)

Answer (score 4):

I have put in a fix for this, will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Next deployment? I think I've seen it fixed already :)